# How to read signals from PLC using opc ua?

Tags: plc, opc-ua, node-opcua

I have a node-opcua server running on my machine. I want to read data from PLC.
From my understanding, OPC Server is used to read/write on PLC.

I have followed the instruction to create server and client from http://node-opcua.github.io/

So, my question is how to read signals from PLC? I am new to IoT and OPC UA. Please guide me.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately you're missing a big piece of the puzzle.

Yes, one of the most common uses of an OPC Server is to allow an OPC Client to communicate with a PLC.

But there's nothing magic about OPC that allows this. This works because that particular OPC server knows how to communicate with each different kind of PLC it claims to support via the native protocol for that PLC. This is a ton of work, it's different for almost every PLC model and brand, and it's why vendors can demand a price for their servers and you won't find many open source alternatives.

Just programming yourself a random OPC server and running it does nothing for you. An OPC server needs to have some kind of useful data for the clients that connect and know how to obtain it. If you're programming the server, then *you* need to know how to obtain it.

---

If you want to get data from PLCs and use OPC, what you should do instead is *buy* or otherwise obtain an OPC Server that knows how to talk to the PLCs you're interested in and then program yourself an OPC Client to interact with that server and get the data you need.

This is the big problem that OPC solved in the beginning: let the vendors worry about the myriad of complicated, legacy, and sometimes undocumented protocols needed to talk to PLCs. Clients who need this data can then just worry about one open standard (OPC).

Answer (score 2):

OPCUA servers are not used to read data from PLCs. OPCUA servers do publish data which can be accessed by OPCUA clients.

If you want to use OPCUA to read data from a PLC you need at least:

- An PLC which can be configured as OPCUA server (Siemens S7-1500 serie is an example)
- An OPCUA client application (http://node-opcua.github.io/ is an option)

Note: there is a big difference between "OPC" and "OPCUA". I am talking about OPCUA since you mentioned the node-opcua library.

Note 2: Kevin Herron is not completely wrong but it sounds a bit misleading to me. The specialized communication drivers he mentions are not part of the OPC server. Some products may be branded as "OPC server which talks to PLCs from brand x,y.." but these products are much more then just an OPC server. OPC is not used to connect to PLCs in this case.

Answer (score 0):

1) what type of PLC?

2) you need to implement communication protocol in node. But, better, consider the implementation of other tools.

3) PROFIT

IMHO node-opcua better designed for publishing internal parameters on node.js application.

For example - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-modbus